# Colors in my server-side `console.log()` while Meteor is in development mode

Tags: javascript, meteor, colors, console.log

I'd like to make use of this nifty [npm colors package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colors) when printing to the server side console while running my meteor server.

I'm generating quite a bit of fixture data that I'd like to be able to color code to make it easier to read in the console.

I've tried both:

```
import colors from 'colors/safe'
console.log(colors.red("Generating Fake Data:"))
```

and

```
import colors from 'colors'
console.log("Generating Fake Data:".red)
```

but my console output remains to be:

```
I20160812-19:55:00.427(-4)? Generating Fake Data:
```

With that first part "`I20160812-19:55:00.427(-4)?`" to be blue while "`Generating Fake Data:`" is just grey.

Screenshot:
[image: console.log() screenshot]

So, does anyone know another way I can display colors in my server-side `console.log()`s in meteor?